I'm searching for a movie about a guy who gets trapped in a sex dimension
I saw a movie (sex comedy) in America while i was on a vacation there, I can't really remember but I think it was on Netflix. It should be around 2011 that I saw the movie. 
It's about a teenage guy that got stuck in a sex dimension. The guy got in there via a game or movie, I'm not sure... there are only women in this dimension. The guy falls in love and is able to bring his love back to the real world. I can also remember something about his dad. I think he found his dad in this dimension, he was living like Hugh Hefner in the playboy mansion and decided he wouldn't come back to the real world.
Is there anyone that could help me? I really want to find this movie!

Sounds like the 2009 movie Deep in the a Valley starring Chris Pratt.

The Diamond Jim pool party is very much what you describe in the question. Also that he's one of the guys father.

Plot description:

One night, two friends have a beer when a delivery comes in the form of a vintage porn viewer machine which plays the films of Diamond Jim. They step inside and it transports them to a land where everyone acts like they are in a pornographic film.

Here is the trailer:



